# loop in the bash shell

Tags: bash, loops, vim

I read a file like this:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done < file.txt
```

Sometimes, I can't read the last line.
Open the file with VIM, and exec ":set list", then I can see a "$" at the end of each line.
But, when I exec "cat file.txt":

```
$ cat file.txt
aa
bb$
```

The last line "bb" and the "$" are in the same line.
I think it's a problem.
How can I use "while" to read all lines?
ps:Can vim show newline like \n and return like \r?

I'm a beginner, help!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Vim alerts you to this condition (a missing *newline* (`\n`) character in the last line) is during opening, where `[noeol]` will be in the message.

```
:edit foo
"foo" [noeol] 3L, 42C
```

You can also check later via

```
:setlocal eol?
```

To fix this retroactively (meaning you cannot modify the file's source to avoid creating such files), just `:write` the file from Vim; it'll insert the final newline automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I fix it with shell?

Comment: Sure. A simple `echo >> file.txt` will do.

Comment: @tripleee gives us a link, it contains a better solution. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely because of missing `\n` from end of line OR presence of `\r` in a line.

You can test it by this command:

```
cat -vte file
```

To remove `\r` from end use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/'$'\r''$//' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try "cat -vte file", there's no "$" in the last line in the output. So I think maybe the last line is missing \n.

Comment: Yes it is definitely due to missing `\n` from end of last line.